# Excel with Version Control - Best way to merge excel files?

Tags: microsoft-excel, version-control, merge

What is the best way to allow multiple users to edit the same excel file and later merge the files together with conflict resolution?

Comment: Will this work if people edit the same cell?

Comment: No idea - never done it myself.  Simple enough to try it out though.

Answer (score 1):

Under the Review tab, in the Changes group, select the "Share Workbook" option, check the "Allow changes by more than one user at the same time" box. Now you can save the file on your network, and have multiple users workin in the file at the same time.

Comment: This probably is a good solution, but if you use excel 2016 (and prosumably older versions as well) it significantly cripples funtionality. So users will still have to make sure to unshare, merge cells and share again (loosing all concurrent work at that time) when merging cell, working with tables etc.