# Is there a version control tool for Excel VBA or Excel files?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a version control tool for Excel VBA or Excel files in general? We have an Excel (a template) that we add columns from time to time. Sometimes, we'll add new functions / VBA.

How do I manage this? Could I compare the current Excel file with a previous version (OPTIONAL)? I'd like to be able to review changes to new versions of an Excel file / template.

I'm familiar with GitLab, but I'm not sure if that's the right tool for managing Excel files.

I've seen this, it's not what I'm looking for: [Excel with Version Control - Best way to merge excel files?](https://superuser.com/questions/363244/excel-with-version-control-best-way-to-merge-excel-files)

Answer (score 0):

The native way to do this is with OneDrive.

> Microsoft Office automatically saves versions of your SharePoint,
>   OneDrive, and OneDrive for Business files while you’re working on
>   them. These versions allow you to look back and understand how your
>   files evolved over time and allow you to restore older versions in
>   case you have made a mistake.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/view-previous-versions-of-office-files-5c1e076f-a9c9-41b8-8ace-f77b9642e2c2